# char*** code not working correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I need to solve this exercise this way because the given function needs to have these parameters, the problem is I'm getting core dumped at around the 20th string I read:

```
int load(char *filename, char ***words) {
    char **pt = (*words);
    *words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char s[50];

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0, t;

    while (fscanf(f, "%s", s) == 1) {
        t = strlen(s);
        printf("%d    ", t);
        s[t] = '\0';

        pt = (char **)realloc(pt, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
        pt[i] = (char *)realloc(pt[i], sizeof(char) * (t + 1));

        strncpy(pt[i], s, t + 1);
        printf("%s\n", pt[i]);

        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using pt as a `char**` just to test how this works, the objective is to store in the `***words` the strings in the textfile:

textfile:

```
break
int
case
long
char
continue
return
default
short
do
sizeof
double
static
else
struct
switch
typedef
float
for
unsigned 
goto
while
```

Comment: `t = strlen(s) --> s[t] - '\0'` of `strlen()` worked then `s[t]` is already `'\0'`. Did you know that `malloc()` is not infallible?

Comment: I don't really know what the main problems with malloc can be, I learned how to use it in a very basic way last week in class...

Comment: dont cast return of malloc, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @JoãoGomes Always check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`.

Comment: First the code stores to `pt` where `words` points to then it overwrites this very value in `*words` but continues to use `pt`. Does this make sense? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to use this as a return parameter?

```
char **pt=(*palavras);
```

Here, you get the current value.

```
pt=(char **) realloc(pt,sizeof(char*)*(i+1));
```

now you **overwrite** that value with a maybe-new allocation.

you probably are missing a

```
*palavras = pt;
```

to return this value? Otherwise, you are likely leaking the memory allocated.

Furthermore, you have an incorrect `realloc` here:

```
pt[i] = (char *)realloc(pt[i], sizeof(char) * (t + 1));
```

Because the old value of `pt[i]` is *undefined* (if you are lucky, your kernel or libc initialized this as `NULL`, although you did not request memory initialization.

Comment: My problem right now is not returning, is the fact that I can't read all the textfile because I get a core dump before it :S

Comment: Learn the difference between `realloc`, `alloc` and `calloc`. Then fix your allocation code. Avoid overusing realloc, but mostly use it to *shrink* an overly large allocation to its ginal size.

Answer (score 1):

The array pointer `pt` should be initialized to `NULL` and the final value stored to `*words` just before returning from the function.

Furthermore, you do not set `pt[i]` to `NULL` when you reallocate `pt` here:

```
pt = (char **)realloc(pt, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
```

The reallocated space beyond the previous size is not initialized.
Fix the code this way:

```
pt = realloc(pt, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
pt[i] = NULL;
```

You can actually simplify the code by using `strdup` to allocate the strings:

```
int load(char *filename, char ***words) {
    char **pt = NULL;
    char s[50];
    int i = 0, t;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        for (; fscanf(f, "%49s", s) == 1; i++) {
            t = strlen(s);
            printf("%d    ", t);
            pt = realloc(pt, sizeof(*pt) * (i + 1));
            pt[i] = strdup(s);
            printf("%s\n", pt[i]);
        }
    }
    *words = pt;
    return i;
}
```

I made the function return the number of words loaded into the `words` array, otherwise, there would be no way to know.

Comment: I tought realloc initialized automatically

Comment: @JoãoGomes: no it does not, it preserves the contents of the part that was reallocated to a larger size even if it moves, but the newly allocated bytes at the end are uninitialized, so they can have any random contents.  calling `realloc(pt[i], t + 1)` invokes undefined behavior.